Using Totient Function to find the probability 2 numbers are coprime
What is the probability that two randomly selected numbers are coprime?
I saw the solution to this, it is the product of 1-$\frac{1}{p^2}$ for all primes p.
Before seeing the solution, I tried it a different way and am failing to see the mistake.
Let $\phi$ be the euler totient function.
Let the two numbers be a and b. WLOG, assume a>=b.
The probability is then $\phi$(a)/a, since b has exactly a possibilities, and $\phi$(a) of them are coprime to a.
This means that the probability is the product of 1-$\frac{1}{p}$ for all prime factors of a, p.
a can be any natural number  so the total probability is:
$\sum_{a=0}^\infty \prod_{p|a}\frac{p-1}{p}$
This doesn't give the same answer when approximated with C++. Could someone help me see why.
Thanks!

Since you can't select a number from $\mathbb{N}$ with uniform distribution, what probability distribution are you using to define 'randomly selected'?

First of all, it's important to note that this is not really a "probability": there is no uniform probability measure on the natural numbers.  Rather, we want to take the limit as $n \to \infty$ of the probability that $a$ and $b$ are coprime when $a$ and $b$ are chosen uniformly from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.
OK, so now suppose $\{A, B\}$ are chosen uniformly from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and take $A$ as the larger and $B$ the smaller.  Yes, the conditional probability $\mathbb P [ \gcd(A,B) = 1 \mid A ] = \phi(A)/A$.  But you can't just add those conditional probabilities: rather, $$\eqalign{\mathbb P[\gcd(A,B) = 1] &= \mathbb E\left[ \mathbb P[\gcd(A,B) = 1 \mid A \right] \cr &= \sum_{a=1}^n \mathbb P[A=a]]\; \mathbb P[\gcd(A,B) = 1 \mid A=a]}$$
where $\mathbb P[A=a] = (2a-1)/n^2$.
